# Running roscore and nodes in separate computers

Tags: ros, master, server, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Due to limited storage space, I would like to run my `roscore` and certain important packages in one system (A Jetson TX1 running `ros indigo` on `ubuntu 14.04`) and my subscriber packages in another. Both these systems are on the same router. I believe that Jetson is to be set up as a master/server and the other system should be a client. But how can I set these up?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243905/running-roscore-and-nodes-in-separate-computers/) by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2016-09-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-09-16**:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-09-16**:
Also know that you have to use RSA keys with SSH in ROS, because ROS uses a library for SSH support that doesn't support the newer algorithms. See http://answers.ros.org/question/41446/a-is-not-in-your-ssh-known_hosts-file/ for more details.

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-09-16**:
And if you've already been SSH-ing between the hosts, you'll have to manually remove the keys from ~/.ssh/known_hosts (or remove the whole file) before using ssh again with the `-oHostKeyAlgorithms='ssh-rsa'` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If TX1 is the master, you should run `roscore` on it, and also some nodes that have to run on TX1. You need to know the IP address of TX1, say `192.168.1.10`, and the `roscore` port number, say `11311`.

And the other machine, your PC, for example, should also install ROS. Don't run `roscore` on your PC, just `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.10:11311`. and then run the node directly.

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0